# Keep string in JOptionPane after validation - Java

Tags: java

I have this following method to validate some Ids:

```
public static String[] getAllCartIds(String cartId) {

        int correctId = 0;
        String[] allCartIds = { "" };

        while (correctId != allCartIds.length) {

            correctId = 0;
            cartId = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Type 1 cart ID and press OK.\nIf you want to approve more than 1 cart, type all the IDs separated by a comma.\n\nEXAMPLE:\n\nAAA,BBB,CCC\n\n");

            cartId = cartId.trim();
            cartId = cartId.toUpperCase();

            // Split the cart IDs in an Array and remove whitespaces
            // Sort IDs alphabetically
            allCartIds = cartId.split("\\s*,\\s*");
            Arrays.sort(allCartIds);

            // Validation
            for (int i = 0; i < allCartIds.length; i++) {

                char c = allCartIds[i].charAt(0);

                if (allCartIds[i].length() != 6) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            allCartIds[i] + " does not have 6 digits.\nPlease check again.");
                    break;
                } else if (c != 'A' && c != 'E' && c != 'P') {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, allCartIds[i] + " is an invalid cart ID.\nPlease check again.");
                    break;
                } else
                    correctId++;
            }

        }
        return allCartIds;
    }
```

This method validates the Ids the user types in the JOptionPane and sends back to main().

**The problem is:** let's say the person write like 15 IDs separated by a comma, and one of them is wrong ... the JOptionPane will be called again and the person needs to type again all the 15 IDs.

**My question:** Is there a way to, in case the person types a wrong ID, after the warning, the JOptionPane is called again but it keeps what was typed before, so the person does not need to type all the Ids again, just update the wrong one?

Comment: If you want ideas on how to do it. You could validate the string as they type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the showInputDialog that takes 3 parameters. Null, your message, and the cartId from the previous dialog.

```
cartId = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Type 1 cart ID and press OK.\nIf you want to approve more than 1 cart, type all the IDs separated by a comma.\n\nEXAMPLE:\n\nAAA,BBB,CCC\n\n", cartId);
```

[JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))